# How to edit changable icon scale?

Tags: java, swing, icons, scaling

As I know, to scale icon is toward button itself .
Like this

```
final JButton satu = new JButton((new ImageIcon(((new ImageIcon("images/1.png").getImage().getScaledInstance(50,50,java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH))))));
```

But when I modify to be changeable icon
I don't know how to scale it

is somebody know how to fix it ?

This is the code

```
final ImageIcon iconsatu = new ImageIcon("images/1.png");
final ImageIcon iconSatu = new ImageIcon("images/r1.png");

satu.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    private boolean flag = true;
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        satu.setIcon(flag?iconsatu:iconSatu);
        flag=!flag;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand the question. You know how to scale an image as you demonstrated in your first line of code.

So why can't you simply create two scaled Icons:

```
Icon icon1 = new ImageIcon(((new ImageIcon("images/1.png").getImage().getScaledInstance(...))));
Icon icon2 = new ImageIcon(((new ImageIcon("images/2.png").getImage().getScaledInstance(...))));
```

Although that code is too complicated. You can simplify it by using something like:

```
BufferedImage image1 = ImageIO.read( new File("images/1.png") );
Icon icon1 = new ImageIcon( image1.getScaledInstance(...) );
```